# Navigate Info Button to another screen Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationbar

I have created an information button at the left side of the navigation bar.
How can I allow users to navigate to another view named "AboutViewController" after clicking on the information button?
Please help!! (Below is my codes)

```
UIButton* infoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];
[infoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(viewWillAppear:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *modalButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:infoButton];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:modalButton animated:YES];
[modalButton release];
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would like to tell you that change your `@selector` method with another suitable name like in this case I have given `navigateToAboutView:` . Because the method name which you have given in your code may be present in the same view from which you are going to call!!

Now write the following code in your custom method -

```
- (void) navigateToAboutView:(id)sender
{
    AboutViewController *aboutViewCntrl =[[AboutViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"AboutViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:aboutViewCntrl animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you have passed `viewWillAppear:` as the selector when you add a target to the button, but that selector defines which method is called when the button is tapped. `viewWillAppear:` is a method that is called every time the view is about to be shown, so it doesn't make sense to call it when your button is tapped. So change it to something like `openAnotherView` and create a method like this one:

```
- (void)openAnotherView {
    // Instantiate the view controller.
    AboutViewController *aboutViewController = [[AboutViewController alloc] init]; // or initWithNibName:bundle: if you use Interface Builder.

    // Present the view controller modally.
    [self presentModalViewController:aboutViewController animated:YES]
}
```

If you want to dismiss the about view controller, then use this line in `AboutViewController`:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]
```